# What are the practical advantages of quantum GANs with respect to classical ones?

Tags: classical-computing, quantum-enhanced-machine-learning, speedup

I read some papers on Quantum GANs, for instance [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.06201.pdf) one and [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.00080) one. I also noticed all the main quantum computing frameworks have a tutorial on quantum GANs, e.g. [qiskit](https://qiskit.org/documentation/machine-learning/tutorials/04_qgans_for_loading_random_distributions.html).

However I don't really get what are the practical advantages of the quantum version. Is it a matter of speedup of the convergence of the model ? Is it related to the expressiveness of the model ? In general, what can I expect this quantum version to be better at and why should I choose it ?

Answer (score 1):

Loading Data into quantum circuit is generally a hard problem which by using QGAN we can reduce it's time complexity [Quantum Generative Adversarial Networks for learning and loading random distributions](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41534-019-0223-2). Generally the time complexity of QGAN is $O(ploylog N)$ which exponantialy faster than classical counterpart $O(N)$.

Also there are some use cases in probing the chemical space using thier large hilbert space [Quantum Generative Models for Small Molecule Drug Discovery](https://arxiv.org/abs/2101.03438)

Comment: Can you point me out to an application closer to the field of data science where using the qGANs is indeed better ? I'm a computer scientist exploring this field for the kind of topics I usually work with, then unfortunately a usecase related to chemistry is not helpful for me

Comment: Also, can you please clarify the complexity of what is O(N) vs O(polylog N)? Is it the complexity to perform a training step or maybe the complexity of generating an image  ?

Comment: Basically the QGAN introduced in that paper can be tested in other areas, it's a hybrid quantum generator and classical discriminator so there is a flexibility in building the model. The complicity in for 'low rank matrix computation' or training and predicting.

Comment: Hello, thanks for you answer. I fear I did not understand the last part related to (I guess) the computational complexity